# Can you explain the React link operation / function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hyperlink, event-handling

I have the following piece of code and I'm trying to figure out what it does. Maybe you can help.

```
private toggleScalingHelper = (value: boolean) => {
    this.link(['measure', 'scaling', 'isActive'])({value});
}
```

The function `toggleScalingHelper` is an event for a toggle slider which hides and shows a container(s).

If I follow the "link" function I get to this:

```
export declare abstract class ReactComponent<P = {}, S = {}> extends React.Component<P, S> implements IInputComponent {

protected link: (path: string | number | React.ReactText[], attr?: string | undefined, stateOnly?: boolean | undefined, action?: import("..").IAction<string, unknown> | undefined) => <E, D>(event: E, data?: D | undefined, action?: import("..").IAction<string, unknown> | undefined) => boolean;
}
```

IAction is defined as:

```
export interface IAction<Type extends string = string, Data extends unknown = unknown> {
    type: Type;
    data?: Data;
}
```

IInputComponent is defined as:

```
export interface IInputComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    handleChange?: <T, U>(path: TPath, newValue: T, originalValue: U) => void;
}
```

Any idea what this code does? How does this link operator work?

Comment: This `link` method does not look like a part of React's API. Where does the definition come from?

Comment: I'm googling these types to find what package they are from and I'm not finding anything.  Are you looking at code that's written by a coworker?  It seems like you are dealing with components that make use of inheritance, which is [not recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Comment: @Shlang I agree it doesn't look like this is a native react link. The link method abstract definition is defined as shown (which I haven't been able to decipher). It's like whoever wrote this code was deliberately trying to be abstruse